# Преобразование типов результатов функций, без их последующего использования

Tags: c, c++

Зачем нужно преобразовывать тип результата функции если ты его дальше не собираешься использовать? Сейчас я говорю о простых типах, а не классах (там в принципе можно и оператор преобразования типа переопределить)...

Итак пример, взят [отсюда](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=popen&category=3&russian=4#lbAH):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
       char *cmd = "/usr/bin/ls *.c";
       char buf[BUFSIZ];
       FILE *ptr;

       if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
               while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, ptr) != NULL)
                       (void) printf("%s", buf);
               (void) pclose(ptr);
       }
       return 0;
}
```

Зачем писать `(void) printf("%s", buf);` вместо `printf("%s", buf);` ? Есть ли в этом какой-то потайной смысл?

---

P.S. мне это кажется бессмысленным, однако может это из разряда best practices?

Например, к best practices относится следующая рекомендация: в сравнениях писать константу слева от переменной, чтобы по ошибке, указав "=" вместо "==" не нарваться на трудно уловимый баг, а если поставить константу слева то возникнет ошибка компиляции и баг тут же будет исправлен. Пример:

Писать
`if (12 == a){...}`, вместо `if (a == 12){...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Зачем писать (void) printf("%s", buf); вместо printf("%s", buf);

Я считаю, что бессмысленно. Пример кода приведен явно Сишный. Возможно необходимость писать (void) - особенность какого-то определенного компилятора.

Comment: Какой-то очень экзотичный должен быть компилятор. Просто стиль. А побочный эффект в C эксплуатируется весьма широко. В языке ведь нет даже оператора присваивания.

Comment: Как это нет оператора присваивания? Впервые слышу

Comment: Это об чём (или об ком)? Нет оператора (который statement - не operator) присваивания? Дык нету... Ежели было воспринято как утверждение про отсутствие операции (operator) - тогда извиняюсь.
hint: есть "оператор-выражение", в котором могут быть и операции присваивания (от нуля до n).

Comment: Вы взорвали мой мозг. Получается, statement - конструкции вида while/if/switch etc. Operator - +, -, /, *, ',', <<, >> etc. Все равно это все есть неотъемлемой частью языка. И, увы, собственные операторы и утверждения делать нельзя. Так что смысла разделять их в данном случае нет. Тем более, что и не все операторы можно перегружать.

Comment: <i>указав "=" вместо "==" не нарваться на трудно уловимый баг</i>
вообще проще присвание в блоках if/while/switch не использовать, а писать чуть более громоздкий код. Пример:
<pre>if ((a = func_name(c))==12){...}</pre>
перепишем как
<pre>a = func_name(c);
if (a == 12){...}</pre>
В любом случае, оптимизирующие компиляторы какие-то подобные действия все равно делают.

Comment: 1. statement:
labeled-statement
compound-statement
expression-statement
selection-statement
iteration-statement
jump-statement - это из стандарта по С. Для дальнейшей расшифровки - см. стандарт. 2. = vs == - классическая идиома while (*r++ = *s++); - копирование строки :)

Comment: @gecube "проще присвание в блоках if/while/switch не использовать" а никто его там и не старается использовать, за редкими исключениями разумеется (например, упомянутое копирование строки), данные косяки очень часто возникают в результате опечаток. А если код в части TRUE условия очень часто выполняется например в 60-70% случаев, то иной раз считаешь нормальным попадание туда, и проскакиваешь глазами (часто, уставшими) этот участок, а именно в нем сидит жаба истины :)

Answer (score 0):

Почитал на других форумах об этом вопросе, что я понял:

Некоторые компиляторы выдают warning, когда программист не использует возвращаемые значения. Это просто убирает этот warning, но на производительность это не влияет.

Comment: - Конкретные warning можно убрать инструкцией  #pragma на многих реализациях компиляторов или с помощью ключей командной строки.<p>
- warning - не error, компиляции не мешает.<p>
- Сейчас компиляторы оптимизирующие. Так что видя, что результат выполнения ф-ции не нужен, они по идее могут чего-то там соптимизировать. (void)funcname мог бы более глупым компиляторам давать какую-либо подсказку об оптимизиации, но выглядит это достаточно нелепо.

Comment: (1) Ну опять, три рубля за рыбу. За неисправленные warning'и при компиляции надо карать. Жестоко. C и так весьма небезопасный язык.
(2) Уж в такой-то подсказке оптимизирующие компиляторы не нуждаются. Или это какая-то сильно странная оптимизация.

Comment: Практического смысла (void) не имеет. По поводу карать за warning. Иногда стремление убрать warning приводит к другим ошибкам. Все надо делать с умом.

Comment: Ну пословице "заставь дурака Богу молиться..." лет очень много. И про присваивание в `if` (из комментариев к соседнему ответу) - так на такие вещи компиляторы как правило предупреждения и выдают.